# Show multiple images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qscrollarea

I am new to PyQt4 and I am trying to show images inside a QScrollArea but I only manage to show one and its always the last image. How can I show multiple images inside the QScrollArea? Is there a better way to show multiple images?

Here is my code:

```
scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
scrollArea.setGeometry(210, 150, 800, 450)
highlightLbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
highlight_dir = url + '\\highlighted'
scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
scrollArea.setGeometry(210, 150, 800, 450)
for file in os.listdir(highlight_dir):
    highlighted_img = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(highlight_dir, file))
    highlightLbl.setPixmap(highlighted_img)
    scrollArea.setWidget(highlightLbl)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QScrollArea you can only set a widget, but if you want to show several you must place it using a layout to that single widget. On the other hand in your code you are using a single QLabel and in the loop you are only changing the image, so you only see the last image.

Considering the above, the solution is as follows:

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        url = # ...
        highlight_dir = url + '\\highlighted'

        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        content_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(content_widget)

        for file in os.listdir(highlight_dir):
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(highlight_dir, file))
            if not pixmap.isNull():
                label = QtGui.QLabel(pixmap=pixmap)
                lay.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On the other hand if there are many images in the folder the widget will delay in displaying and that may be unpleasant for the user, a possible alternative is to use an iteration with a QTimer to load the images little by little.

```py
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        url = # ...
        highlight_dir = url + '\\highlighted'

        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        content_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        self._lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(content_widget)

        self.files_it = iter([os.path.join(highlight_dir, file) for file in os.listdir(highlight_dir)])

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
        self._timer.start()

    def on_timeout(self):
        try:
            file = next(self.files_it)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(file)
            self.add_pixmap(pixmap)
        except StopIteration:
            self._timer.stop()

    def add_pixmap(self, pixmap):
        if not pixmap.isNull():
            label = QtGui.QLabel(pixmap=pixmap)
            self._lay.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PyQt5:

```py
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        url = # ...
        highlight_dir = url + '\\highlighted'

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        self._lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(content_widget)

        self.files_it = iter([os.path.join(highlight_dir, file) for file in os.listdir(highlight_dir)])

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, interval=1)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
        self._timer.start()

    def on_timeout(self):
        try:
            file = next(self.files_it)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(file)
            self.add_pixmap(pixmap)
        except StopIteration:
            self._timer.stop()

    def add_pixmap(self, pixmap):
        if not pixmap.isNull():
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel(pixmap=pixmap)
            self._lay.addWidget(label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```